# "Too many points" when using gdal2tiles.py in EPSG:4326

Tags: gdal, carto, tiles, gdal2tiles

I want to put a custom map onto cartodb, which, I believes, requires EPSG 4326. When I try making tiles with gdal2tiles, using a 4326 georeferenced image, I get the following error:

ERROR 1: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.

If I try to use other projections, gdal2tiles will work fine but they show up in the completely wrong place on cartodb.

Answer (score 1):

Cartodb will also accept 3857. This also didn't work using gdal2tiles.py but it did work with gdal2tilesp.py. So what worked was this:

```
python gdal2tilesp.py -s epsg:3857 rempMap4326_r1.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parallel version from reinventing geospatial or skip python and use.gal_translate and gdaladdo